# What may be the purpose of comparing numbers with a custom comparator in Java?

Tags: java, compare, comparator

I have a homework assignment that includes creating `min()` and `max()` methods for a custom set class of `Integer`s that take `Comparator<Integer>` objects as parameters. I've also seen some similar practice problems online and while I don't have any problems implementing this, I don't understand the reason of doing so.

So, are there any practical applications of using custom `Comparator`s to compare numbers? I would highly value any examples.

Comment: Because you're not always comparing numbers. Imagine you're comparing `Person`s, for example, where being "greater" means your name comes later lexicographically, or you're ordering some product by price.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I understand the point of using comparators to compare custom classes, and my question was specifically about the numbers. I can come up with some clever Comparators for numbers (for example, comparing by the first/last/third/other digit), but I cannot imagine the possible uses of these things

Comment: That is a really good question, because thare are few to none use cases for a custom number comparator.
I can only imagine one being useful if the comparator itself brings context / knowledge to the compare.
E.g. working out which number is closer to some (maybe changing) value.
Or maybe mapping the passed values with a mathematical function and working out which value has a higher (or lower) result.

Comment: @Artem Then they're just exercises for practice. That's why they are exercises and not real world problems :)

Comment: @Eskapone yes, I've also been thinking about mapping the numbers with a mathematical function, and thought that there might be some interesting cryptographic algorithms that utilize such comparators. However, I found none :(

Comment: A comparator is useful for numbers if you want to sort in descending order for example. Another not so simple example is that you want to sort the distance to some fixed number. Imagine you have a set of points `[0, 3, 5, 8, 10]` on a line and you are at point `6`. Now you want to sort the points on how far away they are from you: `[5, 8, 3, 10, 0]`. `5` is the nearest with a distance of `1`. `0` is the farthest away with a distance of `6`. I would imagine there are a lot more examples and also more complicated ones.

Comment: @JANO Thanks, this is an interesting example

Comment: One good way for using a Comparator<Integer> is when you want to sort a List<Integer> in a, say, non-standard way. Following your previous comment, you could maybe sort by the sum of digits, or by the last digit by applying `% 10`. - Or maybe sort by the odds of rolling two dice. So 1 and 12 are lowest, then 2, 11, etc.

Comment: Just thought of another example: Imagine that in the array are the transactions of your bank account in the last week: `[-10, 100, 500, 1, 2, -80,-120]`. `-100` means you payed `$100` to someone and `100` means you got `$100`. Now, you are interested in the transactions with the highest volumes: `[500, -120, 100, -80, -10, 2, 1]`. For this, you need a custom comparator that is ignoring the sign (uses absolute values).

Comment: @JANO this is very smart indeed. Thanks again!

Comment: @JANO I'm a bit wary of those examples. Having those values as simple arrays of integers (especially this latest example with bank transactions) instead of having them contained in actual types to me would be bad design, so I'm not sure those should be considered examples of **good** use of a `Comparator`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca You are right! I would never design these things (e.g. bank transactions) in such a way. I only wanted to give some simple examples that show different orderings of numbers can make sense.

Comment: Since `Integer` is not an application specific type, the use cases should be described on a more abstract level as well (as otherwise you’ll always end up at Federico klez Culloca’s comment, an application specific type would be more appropriate). So JANO’s example can be generalized to “sort by order by magnitude”. Another case would be unsigned sort (`Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::compareUnsigned)`) and even sorting by number of one bits (`Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::bitCount)`) has some applications…